# my own Python implementation of OpenCV Bruteforcematcher is slower than OpenCV's implementation

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to write my own bruteforcematcher that takes 2 image descriptor lists as an argument and returns the best matches. It should have the same functionality as the opencv BFMatcher.match(dest1, dest2).
Currently, I am doing it by calculating the euclidean distance between each keypoint which takes over 27 seconds for the 4 images I am testing it with (I am taking the combinations of all images (6 combinations) and calculating the matches between them)

However, when I do the same thing with BFMatcher.match(), it only takes about 0.016 seconds, which means there is some fundamental implementation difference.

Does anybody know how opencv implements this algorithm?

Here is my current code:

```
combs = list(combinations(descriptors, 2))
    for c in combs:
        descriptor1 = c[0]
        descriptor2 = c[1]
        for keypointctr in range(len(descriptor1)):
            distances = []
            for keypoint2ctr in range(len(descriptor2)):
                distances.append(np.sqrt(
                    np.sum(np.square(np.array(descriptor1[keypointctr]) - np.array(descriptor2[keypoint2ctr])))))
                keypoint2ctr += 1
            min_distance = min(distances)
            mindistances.append(min_distance)
```

For clarification: The list "descriptors" contains the descriptors of all 4 images (so the array has length 4). 4 choose 2 = 6 combinations that have to be checked. This results in a runningtime of 27 seconds on my machine.

Comment: "Does anybody know how opencv implements this algorithm?" -- the source code is on github... | One fundamental difference is that you're doing it in Python. | Provide a proper [mcve], so we can reproduce it.

Comment: python is an interpreted language, not a compiled/JITed language. of course it'll take longer.

Comment: Wait, so does opencv-python just wrap around the C++ version? Got you.

Comment: of course, did you think anyone would reimplement the entire library in plain python and then maintain both versions?

Comment: I guess I did. Thanks for answering my question.